# GORM Behavior In Controller

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm having an issue in a Grails controller. The controller's logic is to perform a check of some data (by a service call) and then if that service returns true, then save the data. However, when the check takes place and fails, the data is still persisted...

Here is basic controller action code (criteria.isMet and criteria.msg are values returned by the service method via a map):

```
    def save() {
    {
         def object = new Domain(params)
         object.name = "OBJECT"
         def criteria = service.isCriteriaMet(object)
         if(criteria.isMet){
             object.save(flush: true)
             render(view: "show", model: [objectInstance: object])
         }else{
             render(view: "create", model: [objectInstance: object])
             object?.errors?.rejectValue("id", "default.message", [message(code: messageLabel)] as Object[], criteria.msg)
         }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace pointing to? If you're executing a query against the same table/domain object hibernate will do a flush to try an persist the dirty objects (which your newly created object would be dirty) and save it at that time. (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Comment: I modified the code to what I have posted in the question and it no longer throws any error. However, it still saves the object (when I don't want it to). Is there a way to stop this behavior? I tried doing an object.lock() after the object.name ="OBJECT" but that does throw an error that the item can't be locked when it hasn't been persisted which makes perfect sense. Any thoughts?

Comment: [discard](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html) the object if criteria is not met by calling `object.discard()` in else block.

Comment: It still saves even with the object.discard in the else block.

Comment: Are we sure that the criteria is **not** met?

Comment: I agree with @dmahapatro.  Also depending on what you're doing in your service to determine `isCriteriaMet` may be able to be pulled into a validation (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#validation)

Comment: I checked the isMet variable and it is indeed false. @JarredOlson the validation is fairly intensive (spans multiple smaller method calls and uses methods in a different service as well), is it possible to call the isCriteriaMet from the Domain class in the custom validator? It seems the custom validator only accepts a closure?

Comment: @BrandonWagner you could have a custom validator call a static method.  If you logic is largely checking attribute values I would probably suggest it.  If you're doing some DB access or web service calls in your validation I would probably suggest what you're doing.  The thing it would buy you (whether it's good or bad is up to you) to have the logic in the custom validator is you wouldn't have to always check `isCriteriaMet` before calling save because it would automatically happen.

Comment: @BrandonWagner can you supply the `isCriteriaMet` code?  Maybe it's something going on in there??  You could run a quick test of commenting out that line of code and changing the if check to `if(false) {` to see if the service is what's causing your object to try to be persisted.